# Update through Linq-to-SQL DataContext not working

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I have created a small test for updating table using Linq-to-SQL DataContext as follows:

```
using (pessimistic_exampleDataContext db = new pessimistic_exampleDataContext())
{
   var query = db.test1s.First(t => t.a == 3);

   if (query.b == "a")
      query.b = "b";
   else
      query.b = "a";

   db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

But after executing this code in a console application in Main method, when I select records from the table, the record is not updated.

I have debugged through the code, and it is not even throwing any exception.

What can be the problem ?

Comment: It's not updating a debug copy of the db ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Table in Database does not have a primary key, therefore DataContext is not able to update it, I catched this error by inserting another code snippet in the code for inserting a new record into the database using Datacontext and then submitChanges(). In this case it threw an exception telling me that Table does not have a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. In SQLServer2008, we need to drop and create the table again. I did so and the code worked perfectly.